# SQL Query to get only Unique values based on Status

Tags: sql

I have this following table, I would like to get the products which has only Inactive Status. Some of the Products has both Active and Inactive Status. But, I don't want them in the final list. I needed only the Products which has only Inactive Status.

```
+-----------+----------+
| ProductID |  Status  |
+-----------+----------+
|    152141 | Active   |
|    152141 | Inactive |
|    157874 | Active   |
|    152478 | Inactive |
|    152478 | Inactive |
|    157875 | Active   |
|    157875 | Active   |
|    157875 | Inactive |
+-----------+----------+
```

and desired results are here.

```
+-----------+----------+
| ProductID |  Status  |
+-----------+----------+
|    152478 | Inactive |
+-----------+----------+
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a not in the productID Active

```
select distinct ProductID, Status
from my_table  
where ProductID not in (
  select productID from my_table where status = 'Active'

)
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: what you did to format the table? I was not able to make the table.

Comment: what do you mean .? . explain better

Comment: when i made my question, i was trying to put the data in the table. However, i didn't see the table and it was scrambled.  Then, you edited the table properly.

Comment: I understand  .. i have formatted  the question using the {}  above the question textarea .. .. If you edit a question there is a toolbar above the textarea with all the command for properly format the question text ..

Answer (score 0):

Do a `GROUP BY`, make sure there are only Inactive rows.

```
select ProductID, Status
from tablename
group by ProductID
having min(Status) = 'Inactive'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like (for Oracle):

```
SELECT ProductId
FROM TableName
MINUS
SELECT ProductId
FROM TableName
Where Status = 'Inactive'
```

Or, using `EXCEPT` (for SQL Server):

```
SELECT ProductId
FROM TableName
EXCEPT
SELECT ProductId
FROM TableName
Where Status = 'Inactive'
```

Thanks to @jarlh for the comment.

Comment: `MINUS` is product specific, and the question has no dbms specified. `EXCEPT` is the ANSI SQL alternative. Besides, OP wants the id's with only Inactive rows.

Comment: You will still get both active and inactive rows... (Since status is selected.)

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/74f9a/3/0

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (ProductID int, Status varchar2(8))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO Table1 (ProductID, Status)
         VALUES (152141, 'Active')
    INTO Table1 (ProductID, Status)
         VALUES (152141, 'Inactive')
    INTO Table1 (ProductID, Status)
         VALUES (157874, 'Active')
    INTO Table1 (ProductID, Status)
         VALUES (152478, 'Inactive')
    INTO Table1 (ProductID, Status)
         VALUES (152478, 'Inactive')
    INTO Table1 (ProductID, Status)
         VALUES (157875, 'Active')
    INTO Table1 (ProductID, Status)
         VALUES (157875, 'Active')
    INTO Table1 (ProductID, Status)
         VALUES (157875, 'Inactive')
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

Query -

```
SELECT distinct t1.ProductID, t1.Status
from Table1 t1
where t1.Status = 'Inactive'
and not exists (
  select 1 from Table1 t2
  where t2.ProductID = t1.Productid
  and t2.Status = 'Active');
```

Output -

```
PRODUCTID   STATUS
152478      Inactive
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.ProductID, t1.Status
FROM tblProduct t1  
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                 FROM tblProduct t2 
                 WHERE t2.Status = 'Active'
                 AND t2.ProductID = t1.ProductID)
AND t1.Status = 'Inactive'
GROUP BY t1.ProductID, t1.Status;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `NOT EXISTS` with the filtration (`Status = 'Active'`) that you don't want :

```
select distinct t.*
from table t1
where not exists (select 1 
                  from table t2 
                  where t2.ProductID = t1.ProductID and 
                        t2.Status = 'Active');
```

You can also use `GROUP BY` clause

```
select ProductID, max(Status) as Status
from table t
group by ProductID 
having min(Status) = max(Status) and min(Status) = 'Inactive';
```